# WCF - list in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I'd like to get country's names form one field of list and put them to the comboBox:

```
    public TravelAgencyResponse GetInformation(TravelAgencyRequest request)
    {
        TravelAgencyResponse response = new TravelAgencyResponse();
       // response.Offers = new OfferDto();
       response.Offers = new List<DataTransferObjects.OfferDto>();            
       response.Offers.Add(new DataTransferObjects.OfferDto()
        {
            IdOffer = 0,
            KindOfAccommodation = "Hotel",
            Country = "Spain",
        });

        response.Offers.Add(new DataTransferObjects.OfferDto()
        {
             IdOffer = 1,
             KindOfAccommodation = "Hotel",
             Country = "Italy",
         });

       response.ThisOffer = (from offer in response.Offers
                              where offer.Country == request.Country
                              select offer).FirstOrDefault();
        return response;
    }
```

I thought that I can use LINQ without *FirstOrDefault()* but I can't do that in this situation.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri baseAddr = new Uri("http://localhost:1232/TravelAgencyService/SimpleTravelAgencyService/");
        ChannelFactory<ITravelAgencyService> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITravelAgencyService>(new WSHttpBinding(),
            new EndpointAddress(baseAddr));
        ITravelAgencyService proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        var response = proxy.GetInformation(
            new TravelAgencyService.Messages.TravelAgencyRequest()
            {
                Country = textBox1.Text
            });

        comboBox1.Items.Add(response.ThisOffer.Country);
        listBox1.Items.Add(response.ThisOffer.Country);

    }
```

I tried put these information in ComboBox like that:

```
 comboBox1.Items.Add(response.ThisOffer.Country);
```

and I give only the first country or like that:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(response);
```

and I don't get anything.

my first steps with WCF! Be understanding, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand your question correctly, you want to fill a ComboBox with all the countries that are contained in any `response.Offers`'s `Country` property, correct?

Since you mentioned you are new to WPF, I'll skip the part about [MVVM and DataBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial) and show you a way it can be done with what you have now.

First you need to "extract" all the countries from the `Offers`, preferably only once and sorted alphabetically.

```
List<string> countries = response.Offers
    .Select(o => o.Country) // We only need the "Country" of the offer
    .Distinct()             // Every country only once
    .OrderBy(c => c)        // Sort by name
    .ToList();              // make a List<string> out of it
```

Instead of adding items manually, I'd recommend assigning all of them at once, by setting the `DataSource` property.

```
comboBox1.DataSource= countries;
```

You need to make sure however that `Items` is empty, manually added items and `DataSource` do not work well together.

If you want to pre-select a certain country (e.g. the one from `ThisOffer`) you can set the `SelectedItem` property of the ComboBox:

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = response.ThisOffer.Country;
```

Comment: But I can't use List<string> for my data -
_ error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)_

And I get the information that ComboBox doesn't contain a definition for  _ItemsSource_, _DataSource_ is it the same?

Comment: @KlaudiaW. I updated the statement, you need to call `ToList` too, As for `ComboBox` doesn't contain a definition for ItemsSource: I thought you are using WPF, my mistake. Yes you should be able to use `DataSource`, I'll update the answer.